# Configuring a package in React/React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how do we configure a package in **React (in-general).**

In NodeJS, We have singleton so we can create an external file, say (`./firebase-config.js`) and then import it in our main `Index.js` file (starting point of our node application).

In react till now, I am used to configuring it in `Index.html` but now I am using react-native **which does not have DOM** so I can't put my configuration there.

Take `index.js` or `app.js` (considering cli version where index.js is the root and app.js is immediate children having all other children) from where I have my config folder at `./src/config/flamelink.js` and this to be my configuration

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import flamelink from 'flamelink';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>', // required
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>', // required
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>', // required
  projectId: '<your-project-id>', // required
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket-code>', // required
  messagingSenderId: '<your-messenger-id>' // optional
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const app = flamelink({ firebaseApp });
```

**Question:** Where should I import it to configure it? or will it React-native work just like node and by just importing, things would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can just have your configuration in, say, `firebase-config.js`, which might look like

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>', // required
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>', // required
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>', // required
  projectId: '<your-project-id>', // required
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket-code>', // required
  messagingSenderId: '<your-messenger-id>' // optional
};
export default firebaseConfig;
```

and then do

```js
import firebaseConfig from './firebase-config';
```

elsewhere in your code.